# VBA to create a Pivot Table from a Variable Dataset

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have written the below code to create a Pivot Table from a variable data set, to show me how many Students have received what range of score within a certain grade. However it returns a Run time error 5 message, with lines 8-11 highlighted by the debugger. However I can't work out what's going wrong

Apologies if this is basic, I'm new to VBA!

(I have commented line 15 because the specific pivot table does not need any Column fields)

```
Sub create_pivot()
    Dim mysourcedata, mydestination As String
    Dim lr As Long
    
    lr = Sheets("PPM").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    mysourcedata = "PPM!R1C1:R" & lr & "C" & Sheets("PPM").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    mydestination = "Pivots and Graphs!R13C2"
    
    Sheets("Pivots and Graphs").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=mysourcedata, Version:=8).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=mydestination, TableName:="PivotTable5", _
        DefaultVersion:=8
        
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5")
        .PivotFields("Grade").Orientation = xlPageField
        .PivotFields("Range").Orientation = xlRowField
        '.PivotFields("ColumnField").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("Student Number").Orientation = xlDataField
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried googling however I could not see a clear answer, seems there's multiple ways of writing the command in VBA to come to the same outcome!

Comment: SourceData and TableDestination require ranges. Use `Set` when assigning the two variables, and use the Range syntax.

Comment: Since your worksheet name contains a space, trying wrapping it within single quotes `mydestination = "'Pivots and Graphs'!R13C2"`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you can use `Range` objects without needing to create string representations of them:

For example:

```vb
Sub create_pivot()
    
    Dim mysourcedata As Range, mydestination As Range
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, wb As Workbook
    Dim pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or activeworkbook for example
    With wb.Sheets("PPM")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set mysourcedata = .Range("A1", .Cells(lr, lc))
    End With
    
    Set mydestination = wb.Worksheets("Pivots and Graphs").Range("B13")
    
    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                SourceData:=mysourcedata, Version:=8)
        
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=mydestination, _
                TableName:="PivotTable5", DefaultVersion:=8)
    
    With pt
        .PivotFields("Grade").Orientation = xlPageField
        .PivotFields("Range").Orientation = xlRowField
        '.PivotFields("ColumnField").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("Student Number").Orientation = xlDataField
    End With
End Sub
```